# QGridLayout Co-ordinates System

Tags: qt, qt4

I have been trying to figure out how the coordinates of a widget is arrived at.For instance in the qt documentation,i wonder how this is done.

[image: Buttons example]

```
QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;
     layout->addWidget(button1, 0, 0);
     layout->addWidget(button2, 0, 1);
     layout->addWidget(button3, 1, 0, 1, 2);
     layout->addWidget(button4, 2, 0);
     layout->addWidget(button5, 2, 1);

     window->setLayout(layout);
     window->show();
```

How did the author arrive at the coordinates above,did he/she use knowledge from the Cartesian plane ?

Comment: You can think of it as a cartesian system with an inverted Y axis. I.e. x runs from left to right and y from top to bottom. The first number parameter is the Y coordinate, the second is the X coordinate. For the case where there's 4 number parameters, the 3rd parameter is the stretch in Y direction and the 4th the stretch in X direction. You can however also just think of rows/columns (like in a table view for example) as OrcunC suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[QGridLayout](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qgridlayout.html) uses simple row/column logic. Row and Column numbers start from 0 as usual.

```
QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;

layout->addWidget(button1, 0, 0); //Add to row 0 column 0
layout->addWidget(button2, 0, 1); //Add to row 0 column 1

layout->addWidget(button3, 1, 0, 1, 2); //Add to row 1 column 0 and span to row 1 column 1


layout->addWidget(button4, 2, 0);//Add to row 2 column 0
layout->addWidget(button5, 2, 1);//Add to row 2 column 1
```

Is this what you are asking ?

Answer (score 1):

QGridLayout::addWidget has two different forms. 
The first:

```
void QGridLayout::addWidget(QWidget * widget, int row, int column)
```

Adds the given widget to the cell grid at row, column.
The second one:

```
void QGridLayout::addWidget(QWidget * widget, int fromRow, int fromColumn, int rowSpan, int columnSpan)
```

The cell will start at fromRow, fromColumn spanning rowSpan rows and columnSpan columns.

```
layout->addWidget(button2, 0, 1);//button2 will be added to row 0, column 1
layout->addWidget(button3, 1, 0, 1, 2);//button3 will be added to row 1, column 0 spanning 1 row and 2 columns.
```

Reference: [qt doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#addWidget)